# Comparing two hashes generated by password_hash for one password

Tags: php, cookies, hash

So I store users password in database after hashed by password_hash() (php 5.5+).
and then verify user when logging in using password_verify(). but now i want to also store password on users browser with cookies. i hash the same password using password_hash but this time the second part of hash is obviously different. (salt)

because of that, two hashes (the one in database and the one in cookie) are NOT equal. how do i verify them then???

Comment: *"but now i want to also store password on users browser with cookies."* - ***Just don't.*** Plus, I'd sure like to know which site that is, so that I won't register there.

Comment: then how do i use cookies to log user in?

Comment: read about php's sessions

Comment: I use them already, but they are not enough. they expire too soon.

Comment: I was thinking of using Sessions+Cookies

Comment: Nobody likes logging in on a website several times a day. cookies seem the right choice... any better way I don't know of?

Comment: Generate a random token, eg `$token = md5(mt_rand());` store the token in the cookie, put the token and the user's IP in the database with a timestamp. When someone comes back with the cookie and the same IP within your chosen timeframe you can skip password-based login. Also, use SSL to avoid cookie hijacking.

Comment: A time limited nonce created on login and stored in a cookie, but only valid for a limited time

Answer (score 3):

## DO NOT STORE THE PASSWORD ON THE CLIENT SIDE

What you're trying to do is recreate sessions. I'd suggest that you simply use a session.

If you can't for whatever reason, then generate a random string (use a library like [`random_compat`](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat)).

```
$token = random_bytes(16);
```

Store the string in the database:

```
INSERT INTO user_to_token (user_id, token) VALUES (?, ?)
```

However, store the hash so that if your database leaks, an attacker won't know the original token and hence won't be able to steal the session.

```
$query->execute([$userId, hash('sha256', $token)]);
```

Then, set the cookie to the raw value, base64 encoded:

```
set_cookie("token", base64_encode($token));
```

Now, to validate, decode and then hash:

```
$token = hash('sha256', base64_decode($cookie));
```

Then look up the user id from the DB:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_to_token WHERE token = ?
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

store user credential on cookie is high risk.

If you store hashes password on database so you only need pass username and password then will hashes from other file and match it into your database.

ex. login.php
post username and password

usercheck.php
md5(password) and check it into database which already hashes password

Comment: Don't suggest md5 for password hashing: it's so insecure that you might as well suggest storing it in plaintext. OP is already using password_hash()/password_verify() which is far more secure

Comment: @MarkBaker What about `md5($string) + $salt` combination? Can be this considered insecure as well?

Comment: @Yang - Yes.... any variant using md5 is considered insecure, because md5 clashes are too easy to generate.... just don't!

Comment: @Yang - PHP provides strong password functions ([password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)/[password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). There is no excuse not to use them.